# The entity &bar; is not defined

Tags: xml, entity, sublimetext, dtd

I'm trying to call an external DTD to my xml file and I proceeded like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="https://digi.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/schema/tei/heiEDITIONS/tei_hes.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="https://digi.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/schema/tei/heiEDITIONS/tei_hes.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
<!DOCTYPE TEI
[
<!ENTITY % heiEDITIONS_entities SYSTEM "https://digi.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/schema/tei/heiEDITIONS/declarations/heieditions-entities.txt">
%heiEDITIONS_entities; ]>
```

All the DTD entities can be found at the address declared by the ENTITY section.

However when I meet an entity in my xml file, for exemple `&bar;` it says that this entity is not declared. Same for `&iuml;` entity. Though it is when you see the entities in the url ! So I don't understand.

I am using Sublime text as text editor.

Where am I doing wrong ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Due to security concerns about [XML External Entity (XXE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_external_entity_attack) attacks, many processors now disable external DTD fetching by default. That results in your entities being undefined.

Depending upon the tool/processor, you may need to figure out how to enable external entity resolution.

https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html